# How would I determine the number of times a digit that is not Digit Y appears in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list L full of digits or strings, I want to find how many elements are different from a given one. So taking the list below, how would I figure find the elements that are not the digit 1 for example?

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,"hello",1,1,1,1,3,4,6,1,"world",1,1,1,1,3,4,3,"1",1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"welcome",3,4]
```

Comment: `sum(1 for x in lst if x != 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a conditional list comprehension to create a list without that element, and then check it's lenght:

```
l = [1,1,1,1,1,1,"hello",1,1,1,1,3,4,6,1,"world",1,1,1,1,3,4,3,"1",1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"welcome",3,4]
result = len([x for x in l if x != 1])
```